# SVN: moving files from inside the folder

Tags: svn, bash, shell, unix, version-control

How to move *all* files (including .htaccess etc.) using `svn move https://example.com/repos/123/* https://example.com/repos/`?

It says "svn: Path `https://example.com/repos/123/*` does not exist in revision NN"

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but all files are under version control, right?

Comment: @Daniel Gehriger: it does exist. The problem is svn thinks that the dir is not "123", but the "123/*".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

svn move does not support wild cards. In the SVN redbook they state that this command can *"Move and schedule a file or directory"*:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html

You therefore have to call svn move for each file in the directory.

I suggest you to write a short script that does this for you or try to use one of the Subversion GUI tools.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use wildcards with repository URLs.

You need to check out `https://example.com/repos/123/`. Then run `svn move foo\123\* foo\` and commit.

Comment: You want say there's no ability to get done all directly in repository?

Comment: Yes, unless you obtain a list of all files and directories inside `123` and run `svn move` for each of them (eg. from a script). But you'll end up with a new revision for each of them. By performing the `move` on the local WC, you bundle all moves into a single revision.